# group waterline-results by day

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to figure out how I can print an overview of log-files.

For that I want to return a list with the peek-entry of each day.

```
module.exports = {

  overview: function(req, res) {
    var query = streamlog.find({ groupBy: ['created'], max: ['ogg'] });
    query.exec(function (err, matchingRecords) {
        res.ok(matchingRecords);
    });
  },

};
```

That solves only part of the problem since items which differ only by seconds/minutes/hours are not considered the same when using above groupBy.

I'm using mongo, if that might help

Comment: It IS specific to waterline/sails since plain js/node-solutions are always processing the content after it was received by the db. Depending on the amount of data that is not plausible

Comment: I don't' understand. You saying it is specific to waterline / sails, but your comments below my answer request that the date be formated before sails / waterline have consumed the data. That would seem to me to be a pure mongo question.

Comment: I'm just speaking about the server. I'm sending a request to mongo through waterline and its adapter and receive that through waterline (which sits in between my code and mongo). The power of group by is that the db (whatever it may be) is able to do the heavy lifting.. I don't want to do that in my JS (i.e. not after consuming the data). That's why the js/node-tags are misleading.. I want to know how I can get waterline to send proper groupBy-Requests to the according db-adapters. If that is not possible: so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you require is a native transformation of the value that mongo will be returning there is no clear way to do what you want it to do.

You could use `query.native()` but that does not allow you to use the waterline group.

You could also create another column in your collection called `createdDate`, this column would get updated with the shorter date format so that you can perform your aggregate function.

Sorry for the confusion, but in short you can not group on values that require a transformation. You would have to preform something before / after to achieve this effect what your looking for.

Comment: How can I receive the formatted date? I am not talking about the plain mongo-driver.. I'm using waterline for a reason. Also, thanks for your answer that show how to do it afterwards, but this was not the question.

Comment: receive it where? In the client, on the server?

Comment: In this comment I was refering to `If your using mongo 3.0 you can return a date formated.` How can I do that with waterline? I know how to do that with pure mongo-drivers, but with waterline already there it would be nonsense not using the functions it already offers, as long as it is also possible via them

Comment: with waterline you can define it as a custom attribute. See http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, but that still does not solve the grouping.. The way you have done it groupBy is completely unneeded and just bloats the query up / makes it slower. `find()` would be sufficient in your example

Comment: ah, you make good points. My answers are straight gibberish then. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A way to partly solve the problem via mapReduce

```
    overview: function(req, res) {
      streamlog.native(function(err, collection) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);

        collection.mapReduce(
          function() {
            // Indonesian dates are formatted as 16/03/1990
            var key = this.created.toLocaleDateString('id');
            emit(key, this);
          },
          function(k, v) {
            var biggest = {
              t: 0,
              v: {}
            };
            v.forEach(function(candidate) {
              if (candidate.ogg + candidate.mp3 > biggest.t) {
                biggest.t = candidate.ogg + candidate.mp3;
                biggest.v = candidate;
              }
            });
            return biggest.v;
          }, {
            out: "log_overview"
          },
          function(error, reduceCollection) {
            reduceCollection.find().toArray(function(a, b) {
              res.ok(b);
            });
          }
        );
      });
    },
```

As this is still a work-around I will not tick my answer and am happy about any answer with better performance then this :/